# GCM Push Server side, which API Key to use?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a bit confused. I have a GCM PHP server side app server that uses a key from Google Developer Console. I can create Android key as per the instructions given in getting started guide here, or I can create a browser key, server key or OAuth key.

Can somebody tell which key I should use on the server side PHP when sending messages via GCM to Android devices?

This is the function that sends the message to GCM

```
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

Obviously the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX string is replaced by my API_KEY in the original code.

p.s: My android is registering fine with the GCM, I have the registration id sent to server as well, it's the send message post request that always returns 401 Unauthorized, I'm afraid I'm using a wrong key?

p.s2: I've tried all 3 sort of API_KEYs without success.

Comment: Please post your server code

Answer (score 2):

Solved

I was concentrating on Android or Server API_KEY but I actually had to use browser key.

Moreover, to test initially I removed all IP addresses from white listing to make sure that's not the factor playing it's role.

Now I have the push service working with above code using Browser API Key and IP restriction in place for white listing.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you include the 'Authorization' header with value 'key=APIKEY'.

ApiKey can be either server key or browser key.

If you define IP whitelist for server key, you can only send messages from the specified IPs.

Comment: Looks like I'm already doing that. Pls take a look at the code i just added to the question