# Which API key for android GCM server

Tags: php, android, api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am confused a little for which API key should I use for the GCM server.
In the documentation it says use android api key, which did not work with me and always gives unauthorized.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
I used server key which worked for me, but I am wondering why the documentation says that?
Am I doing something wrong?

I saw this post also, but I could not get an answer.
[GCM Push Server side, which API Key to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787059/gcm-push-server-side-which-api-key-to-use)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: i dont understand your question, but this [link](https://github.com/rutulpatel/Android-Google-Cloud-Messaging-GCM-using-PHP-Tutorial) would help you for sure.

Comment: @rutulpatel thank you very much. According to the tutorial, Server API key is the right way to do it, not Android API Key. I am still confused about why the documentation says to create Android API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Key is the one that should be used, because the server is the side that send the push notification.